# MSGraph pagination fails with Invalid filter clause when filter used

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

Pagination appears not to work when an advanced filter is used?
I'm able to get the first result set but the first call to `users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();` fails with 'Invalid filter clause'
If I don't use a filter then no problem.

```
queryOptions = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Option>
{
    new QueryOption("$count", "true"),
    new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
};
filter = "startswith(companyName, 'US')";

List<User> allusers = new List<User>();
var users = await graphClient.Users
   .Request(queryOptions)
   .Filter(filter)
   .GetAsync();
while (users.Count > 0)
{
    allusers.AddRange(users);
    if (users.NextPageRequest != null)
    {
        users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
return allusers;
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue myself. Apparently, something broke with one of the new SDK version as it works for me with the Microsoft.Graph v3.0.0.

If it's no problem for you to work with an older version I would "downgrade" to a lower version where this works and wait for Microsoft to solve it.

I've created an [issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1095) on the msgraph-sdk-dotnet GitRepo in case you want to stay updated

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code.

```
        List<Option> options = new List<Option>
        {
            new QueryOption("$count",
                  "true"),
           new QueryOption("$filter",
                  "startswith(companyName,'A')"),

           //Creating header
           new HeaderOption("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual")
        };

        try
        {
            IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await graphClient.Users
            .Request(options)
            .GetAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I no longer get an error when I make this call: groups = await groups.NextPageRequest.GetAsync(); but I also do not get any results.

Comment: That means there could be no results matching your filter.

Comment: users.NextPageRequest != null indicates that there are more results matching my filter